# How to read drawing image (.dwg) from byte array

Tags: c#, wpf, image

I have one WPF application in which I am uploading autocad drawing files (.dwg), convert it to byte array and save to database. When I read back that file from byte array, I am getting following error :

```
No imaging component suitable to complete this operation was found.
```

My code to convert in byte array is below :

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(dlg.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
byte[] data = new byte[fs.Length];
fs.Read(data, 0, System.Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));
fs.Close();
```

I am trying to get image from byte array using below code :

```
BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
 bi.BeginInit();
 bi.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.None;
 bi.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.Default;
 bi.StreamSource = new MemoryStream(data);
 RenderOptions.SetBitmapScalingMode(bi, BitmapScalingMode.Linear);
 bi.EndInit();
```

Above code works fine for other image files like jpg, png, bmp, gif. but not working for dwg file. Can anybody guide me what's wrong in my code ?

Thanks

Comment: The problem has little to do with wether or not you read it as byte array or wether or not it has passed through a database. You are trying to display a dwg file as an image. It is not an image. It is CAD data.

Answer (score 1):

Times ago I was searching for DWG library in C# and found this one: 
http://www.woutware.com/cadlib.html, but after never used it.

You can not threat DWG files like ordinar image files, DWG is fairly complicated format for storing 2D and 3D data as well. And years ago also was a  subject of frequent change and all licensing mess.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think it's paid library. Can you please give me sample code to convert in dwg or BitmapImage which are free ?

Answer (score 0):

You have answered it yourself!

> Above code works fine for other image files like jpg, png, bmp, gif.
>   but not working for dwg file.

For this to work correctly deserialise the byte array back to as "dwg file" itself and use some APIs to convert it to a bitmap and use that as the image source.

Comment: Can you please give me sample code to deserialize byte array back to dwg file ? how can I know that byte array which need to convert contains dwg file ? it might be png, jpg...

Answer (score 0):

Try using a type converter

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(dlg.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
byte[] data = new byte[fs.Length];
fs.Read(data, 0, System.Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));
fs.Close();
TypeConverter tc = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(BitmapImage));
BitmapImage bitmap1 = (BitmapImage)tc.ConvertFrom(data);
```

Comment: I need System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage in return not System.Drawing.Bitmap.

Comment: @UpendraChaudhari than use TypeConverter as BitmapImage se update

Comment: It gives error : "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Answer (score 0):

Try using `strm.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);` because it may be possible you must have gone past through the stream with read

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use http://www.opendwg.org/ 
Although not free, it is non-profit.

But it will only parse the dwg file for you into collection of lines, circles, polygons etc.
You still need to piece together and render the image.